# Send file in response from Java HTTP server

Tags: java

I'm using Ember for front-end and Java for back-end. On typing localhost:8080, I need to show the Ember homepage index.html. Previously, I used Node.js and the below line did the trick

```
res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
```

Now on shifting to Java, I'm unable to achieve the same result. I tried the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new HHandler());
    server.createContext("/getbookarray", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

static class HHandler implements HttpHandler 
{
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException 
    {
        File file = new File("..\\public\\index.html");
        String response = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        t.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=" + encoding);
        t.getResponseHeaders().set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();
    } 
}
```

But, unfortunately I'm getting the below error on trying to load the home page.

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

The same Ember application when processed using Node.js works fine. I guess I'm not sending the HTTP response properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to use `os.flush()` before `os.close()` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's a syntax error in your HTML page. Nothing to do with this code whatsoever. And `flush()` before `close()` is redundant @edkeveked

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have an issue with the path of your file. Also notice that the `readFileToString` is deprecated.

Here is a working server that will send your `index.html` to your frontend.

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class myServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("server ...");
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new HHandler());
        //server.createContext("/getbookarray", new HHandler());
        //server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
        //server.getExecutor();
    }

    static class HHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();



            String line;
            String resp = "";

            try {
                File newFile = new File("src/index.html");
                System.out.println("*****lecture du fichier*****");
                System.out.println("nom du fichier: " + newFile.getName());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(newFile)));

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    resp += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            h.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, resp.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(resp.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the lightweight server [nanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd). With the following code you can send your `index.html` file to your frontend also.

```
import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

import java.io.*;

public class App extends NanoHTTPD {

    public App() throws IOException {
        super(8080);
        start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
        System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browsers to http://localhost:8080/ \n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new App();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(NanoHTTPD.IHTTPSession session) {

        File newFile = new File("src/index.html");
        System.out.println("*****lecture du fichier*****");
        System.out.println("nom du fichier: " + newFile.getName());


        String line;
        String reponse = "";

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(newFile)));
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                reponse += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newFixedLengthResponse(reponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey edkeveked, I tried your suggestion. But I'm still getting the same error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Thank you @edkeveked . I will test this out tonight and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Okay @GiridharanJ, let me know!

Answer (score -1):

Try not reading your file as text but as binary info (sequence of bytes). Because at the end you convert your string read from file to bytes anyway. You can read file using [Files.readAllBytes(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-)